# How to extract data from web 2.0 graphs using a scraper

Tags: screen-scraping

I have recently come across a web page containing a graph object that displays the (x, y) values on the object as the mouse is rolled across it.  Is there any way to automate the extraction of this data?

Answer (score 0):

How is the graph data loaded? If embedded in the page source then you can extract it with xpath or regex. Else use Firebug to see how it is loaded.